# What if there are two identities?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

When we talk about vector spaces(or groups, rings,fields... ), we talk about the uniqueness of identity and for every element a unique inverse being present. Now, what if the identity is not unique? Can two identities exist and lead to formation of one vector space?

Comment: Suppose you have two identities $e_1$ and $e_2$. Then $e_1=e_1e_2=e_2$.

Comment: Several previous duplicates: https://www.google.com/search?q=uniqueness+identity+math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

The standard definition of identity with regards to a binary operation $*$ you have the following definition:

$\forall b\; (b*1)=(1*b)=b$

This is enough to give uniqueness. Suppose $1$ and $e$ are two different identities. Then $1*e=1$ by $e$ being an identity and $1*e=e$ by $1$ being an identity thus $1=1*e=e$ and you have uniqueness.

Comment: And actually, you proved a stronger result : if there is a left identity $e_1$ and a right identity $e_2$ then $e_1 = e_2$

Comment: @max Yes, but I hesitate to point it out much since I didn't prove that two left (or right) identities are equal (as they don't necessarily need to be).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it can be of different reasons:

1. If you have both left and right identity they must all be the same. This is the case for vector spaces.
2. If on the other hand you have left inverse and left identity the left identity must be unique.
3. If you have associativity and no zero divisors you also have unique identity.

The proof for case 1. is quite simple. Suppose whe have left identities $L$ and $L'$ and right identities $R=R'$ we have:

$$L = LR = R = L'R = L' = L'R' = R'$$

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, if you have a left identity $a$ and a right identity $b$ then they are the same (so you have an identity element, which has to be unique), since $$a = ab = b$$

The only situation in which you could have two non-equal "identity elements" is when these are both left identities (and only left identities!), or, of course, both right identities.
An example of this: take the semigroup $\{a,b\}$ with $a \neq b$ and $aa=ba=a$ and $bb=ab=b$. Then $a$ and $b$ are both left identities, and none of them is a right identity.